# Double POST requests for some reason?

Tags: javascript

so in my code below when a user checks or unchecks the input box the page refreshes, so I add a local item to ensure it stays checked/unchecked on reload. For some reason when a user clicks the checkbox it sends DOUBLE post requests!? Any ideas, thanks!

Also, my code SHOULD be only running my checkbox function if the checkbox was clicked but it runs on load!?

```html
<input onclick="checkbox()" type="checkbox" name="check" id="insuranceCheckbox"> 
          Add Shipping Insurance?
            <br>
<script>
if (localStorage.getItem("checked") == "true") {
  document.getElementById("insuranceCheckbox").checked = true;
}
else {
  document.getElementById("insuranceCheckbox").checked = false;
}

function checkbox() {
  if (document.getElementById("insuranceCheckbox").checked) {
    localStorage.setItem("checked", "true");
    let data = {"checkout_id": document.documentElement.innerHTML, "value": "True"};

    fetch("https://botach-test-branch.ngrok.io/newCheckout", {
      method: "POST", 
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => {
      console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
    });
  }
  else {
    localStorage.setItem("checked", "false");
    let data = {"checkout_id": document.documentElement.innerHTML, "value": "False"};
    fetch("https://botach-test-branch.ngrok.io/newCheckout", {
      method: "POST", 
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => {
      console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
    });
  }
  window.location.href = window.location.href
}
```

Comment: How do I do that? I thought I did that by putting it in a function?

Comment: Hm. Maybe you did, but this indentation is a mess and I'm having trouble seeing the overall structure.

Comment: There's a lot of strange stuff going on in here, not  the least of which is `window.location.href = window.location.href`. Why do that?

Comment: @tadman I do that so when it refreshes it would not post again, it still does though...

Comment: Remember there's a lot going on in async JavaScript and one line does not necessarily follow the next. If you want to refresh after the operation is complete that *must* be inside the `then` which fires at the appropriate time. Also since it's 2021 and `async`/`await` is available in virtually every browser you may want to do that instead of the ES5 `then` stuff: `let res = await fetch(...)` inside `async function checkbox()`

Comment: Something really strange is going on with the code formatting, probably because it was HTML tagged as JavaScript. Fixed.

Comment: It's worth noting it's really kind of strange you're using `true`, `"true"` and `"True"` all at the same time. It'd be worth standardizing on one and only one style. Tiny differences like that are how you end up with difficult to debug issues.

Comment: I did all the edits u suggested and now it won't even keep the checkbox check if checked it.

Comment: There's honestly just too much code here and that's a result of a lot of rampant duplication. Write small functions that perform a particular operation, like for example computing `data` given whatever `value` you want, then test that it works fine in isolation. Repeat for other small operations. Your final code should be pretty simple if it just calls a few tested, already known-good functions.

Comment: This would also be a lot less messy if you could use something like jQuery which has a `$` function as that can save a *ton* of code.